# What to include in a "connectionString" for a USER WITHOUT LOGIN?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm watching [this tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=sql-server-2016-new-features-developers&author=lenni-lobel&name=sql-server-2016-new-features-developers-m3&clip=0&mode=live) on Pluralsight on how to implement **Row Level Security** on SQL Server. Following the tutorial, I created a user **WITHOUT LOGIN** that I used to execute tasks by granting permissions on objects.

Now, instead of the Visual Studio Query Editor, I'd like to consume the database using the `RLS` from my application.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {    
   "localConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=UisityDB;
    User Id=AppUser;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;
    ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
SqlException: Login failed for user 'AppUser'.
```

The question is: `How would a connectionstring for Loginless user look like?`

Thanks for helping

Comment: AFAIK, one cannot connect using a user without a login unless it's a contained database user with a password. Does the tutorial actually instruct you to connect with that user or just test RLS with the user, such as with `EXECUTE AS USER = 'AppUser'`?

Comment: The tutorial doesn't say I should connect using `AppUser`. As you just pointed out, `AppUser` is being used to demonstrate how the `RLS` works. My assumption was that I should connect using to the database using `AppUser`. I'm a little confused now. So how do I connect if I can't connect without a password?

Comment: Running the queries in SSMS with `EXECUTE AS USER` is an easy way to test RLS but if you want to test with app code, you'll need to create a principal that can authenticate to the database. That could be a login with corresponding database user or user with a password (contained database or Azure SQL Database).